# Finding the error in my Python function to plot a histogram and return a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram

*The instruction is as following:

```
plotRandomUniformSum(M, N, nBins)
```

Let’s consider what happens when we add `M` uniform random numbers together. Since each random number can be between `0` and `1`, we expect this `sum` will be between `0` and `M`, but somehow we expect that it is more likely for the `sum` to be near the `middle (M/2)` than near the `ends (0 and M)` for `M > 1`. First write a function `randomUniformSum(M)` that adds up `M` uniform random numbers between `0` and `1`. Second, write a function that forms a list of `N` such numbers by calling `randomUniformSum` a total of `N times`. Third, plot the result in a histogram and return the list.
Remember that return means to exit the function. Therefore, you should first plot the histogram and then return the list.

What values should you use for `binMin` and `binMax`?

To answer this, consider the `minimum` and `maximum` values that `randomUniformSum` may assume. Try calling your function four times with `M = 1, 2, 3, 10` setting `N = 1000000` and `nBins = 100` in each case. You will notice that as `M` increases, the distribution looks more and more like a Normal (or Gaussian) distribution. This is an illustration of the Central Limit Theorem, a very important theorem from Statistics which states that as you add more and more independent random variables (from any distribution, doesn’t have to be uniform) the sum approaches a Normal distribution - very cool :-).*

This is what I have so far:

```
def randomUniformSum(M):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(M):
        sum += random.uniform(0,1)
    return sum

def plotRandomUniformSum(M, N, nBins):
    L = []
    for i in range(N+1):
        x = randomUniformSum(M)
        L.append(x)
    hist.plotHistogram(L, nBins = nBins)
```

My autograder for this assignment returns an error that:

> "Test Failed: None != [0.793340083761663, 0.8219540423197268, 0[202687
>   chars]9087]"

with different numbers for all tests.

Where is my error? I can't seem to find where I went wrong.

Comment: You're not returning the list from the `plotRandomUniformSum(M, N, nBins)` function

Answer (score 3):

You're not returning the list from the `plotRandomUniformSum(M, N, nBins)` function

```
def randomUniformSum(M):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(M):
        sum += random.uniform(0,1)
    return sum

def plotRandomUniformSum(M, N, nBins):
    L = []
    for i in range(N+1):
        x = randomUniformSum(M)
        L.append(x)
    hist.plotHistogram(L, nBins = nBins)
    return L # you missed this out

list_of_random_sums = plotRandomUniformSum(10, 1000000, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Second, write a function that forms a list of N such numbers by calling randomUniformSum a total of N times.

Hello, welcome to SO. For me it seems unclear that you've formed a list consisting of `N+1` elements instead of `N`. Try to change `for i in range(N+1):` line with `for i in range(N):`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response and help; I tried to change that and it still gives the same error message unfortunately :(